# How to declare multiple types of a property in API Gateway model with JSON Schema and Swagger?

Tags: amazon-web-services, swagger, aws-api-gateway, jsonschema

According to the AWS docs, models in API Gateway support JSON Schema syntax, however, they export as Swagger OpenAPI specs, where Swagger specification does not fully support many valid JSON Schema structures.

I would like my API Gateway model to have a set of optional text fields, e.g., `message`, but when defined as

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "message": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
```

}

and with body validation enabled, it rejects this model when message is an empty string, or missing. It does that even though `message` is not included in the list of required fields

```
  "required": [
      "message"
    ],
```

Digging around, I found that to allow empty/null string values, one must add a `null` type to the list of property types, e.g.:

```
{
    "type": ["null", "string"]
}
```

This, however, still does not work with API Gateway, nor it properly exports as a Swagger spec YAML.

Is there any way to solve this with API Gateway and Swagger?

Comment: `"type": ["null", "string"]` is not valid in OpenAPI/Swagger 2.0, because it does not support multiple types and `null` as a type. `nullable` will be supported in the next version, OpenAI 3.0. (This was asked before, I'll try to find duplicate questions...) Not sure about the API Gateway part though.

Comment: thanks, that's some valuable input!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Helen, Swagger does not support multiple types nor null as a type.  The will probably prevent your first approach from working with swagger import/export.

However, the internal API Gateway model support does use JSON Schema and may work even though import/export doesn't.  I suggest you try entering your model via the API Gateway console or via the API Gateway CLI.

Comment: How can I then version my API if the only export/import method (swagger) does not support all the features of the API Gateway? Is there maybe some other way to export/import API Gateway models?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me with Open API 3.0 and API Gateway, CDK Typescript:

```
        const model = props.rootApi.dataApi.addModel(`${props.appEnv}-name-${props.apiVersion}`, {
            contentType: 'application/json',
            modelName: `ItemResponseModel${props.apiVersion}`,
            schema: {
                schema: aws_apigateway.JsonSchemaVersion.DRAFT4,
                title: 'ItemResponse',
                type: aws_apigateway.JsonSchemaType.ARRAY,
                properties: {
                    time: { type: aws_apigateway.JsonSchemaType.STRING },
                    endTimestamp: { type: aws_apigateway.JsonSchemaType.STRING },
                    hours: { type: [aws_apigateway.JsonSchemaType.INTEGER, aws_apigateway.JsonSchemaType.NULL] },
                    watts: { type: [aws_apigateway.JsonSchemaType.NUMBER, aws_apigateway.JsonSchemaType.NULL] },
                },
                required: [
                    'time',
                    'endTimestamp',
                    'hours',
                    'watts',
                ],
            },
        })
```

Reference https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_apigateway.Model.html